# Best way to get nested level Views without chaining getChildAt() repeatedly

Tags: android

I've discovered I have a frequent usage pattern where I string together a chain of ugly `getChildAt(index)` calls. My code might look like this:

**View Hierarchy:**

```
  LinearLayout
    LinearLayout
      EditText
      EditText
    /LinearLayout
    LinearLayout
      Button
      Button
    /LinearLayout
  /LinearLayout
```

**The ugly code:**

```
layout = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_createbuddy, null);

String number = 
  ((TextView) ((LinearLayout) layout.getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(1)).getText().toString();
```

Guided by my software development experience, this feels wrong.

**1**: The magic numbers have no readable semantics. It is not easily apparent that `0` is a `CheckBox` or a `TextView`, and `1` is some other widget, and these numbers probably have different meanings in different contexts (layouts).

**2**: If somebody were to ever change the layout, all the numbers might be invalidated

**3**: The chain of calls and casts is ugly and easy to screw up.

### What is the correct replacement to this practice?

Here is a more complete code example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical" >

  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
      android:id="@+id/create_buddy_name"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:ems="5"
      android:hint="Name" />

    <EditText
      android:id="@+id/create_buddy_num"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:ems="5"
      android:hint="Number"
      android:inputType="number|phone" />

  </LinearLayout>

  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    style="?android:attr/buttonBarStyle" >

    <Button
      android:id="@+id/cancelBuddyBtn"
      android:text="Cancel"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="center"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle" />

    <Button
      android:id="@+id/createBuddyBtn"
      android:text="Create"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="center"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle" />

  </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And then I have a DialogFragment:

```
public class CreateBuddyDialog extends DialogFragment 
{
  ...

  public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
  {
  ...

  layout = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_createbuddy, null);

  Button button = (Button) ((LinearLayout) layout.getChildAt(1)).getChildAt(1);

  button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
      String name = 
        ((TextView) ((LinearLayout) layout.getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(0)).getText().toString();

      String number = 
        ((TextView) ((LinearLayout) layout.getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(1)).getText().toString();

      addBuddiesActivity.createBuddyConfirmed(new Buddy(name, number));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct thing to do is use `findViewById()` and make sure the Views you want to get references to have an ID specified in XML. For example,

```
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_createbuddy, null);
EditText createBuddyName = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.create_buddy_name);
Button createBtn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.createBuddyBtn);
// now you can mess with these views
```